# How Do You Parse YAML With Scheme?

Tags: parsing, scheme, yaml

I am new to Scheme but I understand recursion and a few things about parsing in general. Does anybody have experience in how to parse YAML (at least part of the spec) using Scheme/Lisp? At this point, I am not looking for efficiency.

Comment: I would recommend getting a copy of one of the open source implementations listed here: http://yaml.org/ and converting that to Scheme or LISP.

Comment: It looks like this is exactly what the Racket YAML parser did. From their site: "The implementation is ported from PyYAML."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the source of a parser for YAML in Racket:

https://github.com/esilkensen/yaml/blob/master/yaml/parser.rkt

It is a recursive descent parser and would be easy to port to RnRS Scheme.

Documentation:  http://pkg-build.racket-lang.org/doc/yaml/index.html

Comment: I'll take a look. I was hoping for something in the Guile implementation, but Racket comes closer than anything else and shouldn't be too hard to port over if necessary.

Comment: Note that main parser is written using very few non-Scheme constructs.